# How to generate download links for a specific computer using php?

Tags: php, download

I am developing a download center using php.

Users have to buy plans to get download links. Download links are dynamically generated using a hash which is a combination of user ip address, the file path & name and a salt.

This way i let the users to download the files for a period of 24 hours even if their session is expired and not logged in any more (checking their ip address).

At the moment i am looking for a secure way to generate user specific download links not related to the ip address but the computer which the user is using.

This way the user can download the file even if is not loggedin or his ip address change.

Any help will appreciate.

Thx in advance

Comment: Should this work if the link is cURL'd too?

Comment: cURL is not a matter.

Comment: Why can't you generate a random link that expires in 24h then?

Comment: Because the link can be used by others (other computers) to download the file. I want the link to be usable only by one computer. (the computer which the link is generated in)

Comment: That's a pretty interesting challenge. Any ideas so for?